# How to restore windows 10 after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

How do I get Windows 10 back?

I downloaded Ubuntu for my school project but instead of a dual boot, my windows 10 is gone and I cannot access my windows 10 anymore.

I would greatly appreciate some help with this issue.

Comment: It's gone because you selected the wrong option, the installer wouldn't do that on its own. Now you can download the Windows ISO from Microsoft and use it to install (or contact your tech support). The whole process is, obviously, off-topic here. Good luck.

Comment: I hope you had a backup of your data. You should check if there is still an NTFS patition showing in Gparted, but, if not, then all of your previous is gone pretty much for good, since the MFT would have been overwritten.

Comment: Will you add the output of this command: `lsblk -f; sudo parted -l` to your question?

Comment: Did you select "Install side-by-side Windows", or do a clean install? If you did a clean install you're screwed. Hope you made a copy of the product key.